# Heroku run via their node-heroku-client

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

How can i use the `heroku run` command via the [node-heroku-client](https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client)?

I want to drop and create the tables in a database via herokus node-heroku-client, but I don't find the endpoint for that. Is there an endpoint in their rest-api that works like [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#start-a-console).
I could do this in the [webinterface](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/project/settings?web-console=app), but I want to do it programmatically.

Isn't the node-heroku-client suppose to be a wrapper for [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run)?

This is pseudo code of what I need, because the the second endpoint doesn't exist:

```js
const Heroku = require('heroku-client');
const heroku = new Heroku({ token: 'xxx' });

const app_name = 'app_name';

heroku.get(`/apps/${app_name}/dynos`, { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3' } })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)

        // TODO: loop through all dynos and run the command
        const app_id = response[0].app.id;
        const dyno_id = response[0].id;
        const command = 'echo hello world';

        return heroku.post(`/apps/${app_id}/dynos/${dyno_id}/console/run`, {
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3' },
            body: {
                command: command
            }
        });
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: Are you planning to run this _on Heroku_, or elsewhere?

Comment: @Chris anywhere. It should not depend on heroku. Probably Oracle Cloud.

Comment: Got it. Lots of folks are under the impression that they need to `heroku run` stuff from their Heroku dynos and are confused why the Heroku CLI isn't available. They just need to omit `heroku run` and run the command. That's not what you're looking for, though.

Comment: I was about to do it with the heroku cli tool npm-package but that schocked me: 
`21 vulnerabilities (15 moderate, 6 high)`.